# Installed gurobi , not refelecting when importing

Tags: gurobi

I have installed `gurobi`, however it does not get reflected when importing.

I get the following error:

> No module name gurobi

Comment: Through which API are you using (Python? Java? Other?)?  Which OS are you using? Please post  the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: This looks like the Python API is not properly installed or configured.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write which API you are using. If you are using python, you should use `import gurobipy` and not `gurobi`. You also need to setup some environment variables (`GUROBI_HOME`, `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). See [Gurobi quick start guide](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_linux.pdf).